# How to iterate XML nested elements with Nokogiri in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, iterator, nokogiri

I'm trying to iterate over a folder structure in XML with Nokogiri but I'm stuck in this:

```
<test>
   <folder name="Folder A">
      <folder name="Folder A1">
         <file name="a.txt">Cool file</file>
      </folder>
      <folder name="Folder A2"></folder>
   </folder>
   <folder name="Folder B">
      <folder name="Folder B1"></folder>
      <folder name="Folder B2">
         <folder name="Folder B21">
            <file name="b.txt"></file>
         </folder>
   </folder>
</test>
```

So, I want to iterate over this in order to be able to create a tree of folders and files (folders A1 and A2 are inside folder A, folders B1 and B2 are inside folder B, and folder B21 is inside folder B2).

So I'm doing this:

```
nodes = allnodes.xpath('//folder')
nodes.each do |node|
  puts "name => #{node.attributes['name']}"
end
```

but this lists me all the folders (A, A1, A2, B, B1, B2, B21). How can I make it so that I don't check inside the previous folders for more folders, and I then send it to the same recursive function?

Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: Are you asking how to get just the subfolders of a given folder? For example, if you specified "Folder A", you would only get "A1" and "A2"?

Comment: Nice xml structure.. +1

Comment: What do you mean by "How can I make it so that I don't check inside the previous folders for more folders"? The `//folder` gives you each folder exactly once. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I answered the questions below :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use an XPath with `//foo` you find `foo` elements at any level. If you instead use `./foo` or just `foo` then you will only find child elements. Thus:

```ruby
# Given an XML node, yields the node and all <file> children
# Then recursively does the same with every <folder> child
def process_files_and_folders(node,&blk)   
  yield node, node.xpath('file')
  node.xpath('folder').each{ |folder| process_files_and_folders(folder,&blk) }
end
```

The keys to this are (a) recursion (having the method call itself for all the child folders) and (b) capturing the block passed by the user with the `&blk` notation, and then passing that block along to the later calls.

Seen in action:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri.XML(my_xml)
process_files_and_folders( doc.root ) do |folder,files|
  depth  = folder.ancestors.length-1  # Just for pretty text output indenting
  indent = "  "*depth                 # Just for pretty text output indenting
  if folder['name']
    puts "#{indent}Processing the folder named #{folder['name']}"
  else
    puts "#{indent}No folder name; probably the root element."
  end
  unless files.empty?
    puts "#{indent}There are #{files.length} files in '#{folder['name']}':"
    files.each{ |file| print indent, file['name'], "\n" }
  end
end
```

Result:

```
No folder name; probably the root element.
  Processing the folder named Folder A
    Processing the folder named Folder A1
    There are 1 files in 'Folder A1':
    a.txt
    Processing the folder named Folder A2
  Processing the folder named Folder B
    Processing the folder named Folder B1
    Processing the folder named Folder B2
      Processing the folder named Folder B21
      There are 1 files in 'Folder B21':
      b.txt
```

Comment: @Tiago If (and only if) this answer solves your problem, please remember to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/153741). If not, feel free to post a followup comment for more clarification or help.

Comment: @Phhogz enve though I've solved the problem already, I'll try it as soon as I can, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd do as below :

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<-xml)
<test>
   <folder name="Folder A">
      <folder name="Folder A1">
         <file name="a.txt">Cool file</file>
      </folder>
      <folder name="Folder A2"></folder>
   </folder>
   <folder name="Folder B">
      <folder name="Folder B1"></folder>
      <folder name="Folder B2">
         <folder name="Folder B21">
            <file name="b.txt"></file>
         </folder>
   </folder>
</test>
xml

# Here I am collecting all folders, which has at-least one child.
parent_folders = doc.xpath("//folder").select do|folder_node|
  folder_node.xpath("./folder").size > 0
end

# Here I will iterate each parent directory, and would collect the corresponding
# sub-directories names.
parent_directory = parent_folders.each_with_object({}) do |parent_dir,dir_hash|
  dir_hash[parent_dir['name']] = parent_dir.xpath("./folder").collect do |sub_dir|
    sub_dir['name']
  end
end

parent_directory
# => {"Folder A"=>["Folder A1", "Folder A2"],
#     "Folder B"=>["Folder B1", "Folder B2", "Folder B21"],
#     "Folder B2"=>["Folder B21"]}
```

Now, you have a hash `parent_directory`, which maintains all the directory(key)/sub-directories(value) relationship. Now using [`Hash#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) method, you can easily extract the sub-directories, of a given directory. One example -

```
parent_directory['Folder A'] # => ["Folder A1", "Folder A2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you're trying to do, but let's say you are creating a new directory structure on disk on a Linux system.

```
doc.xpath("//folder[not(folder)]").each do |f|
   path = f.xpath("ancestor-or-self::folder").map{|f| f['name']}.join("/")
   system("mkdir -p #{path}")
end
```

Here's what this does:

- The first line finds all the lowest-level folders (leaf nodes in the XML)
- The next line finds the name of all the containing folders and joins them with slashes to get the full "path".
- Finally the system command "mkdir -p" creates the lowest-level folders and every folder inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found out later how to solve it.

Just to clarify, I intended to have a function like this:

```
def create_structure(nodeset, current_folder)
    new_folder = "#{current_folder }/#{nodeset.attributes['name']"
    Dir.makedir(new_folder)
    create_files_in_current_folder(nodeset, new_folder)
    subnodeset = nodeset.xpath('/folder')
    subnodeset.each do |node|
        create_structure(node, new_folder)
    end
end
```

So that I can replicate the structure I have in xml to the filesystem.

So, as to the solution, it was right in front of my eyes. I couldn't use "//folder" but instead "/folder", as the first one will return all of the folders, regardless of their place in the xml structure, and the second one will only return the ones in the root of the current node.

I hope this helps and thanks for everyone's answers. I will try them as soon as I can.